# JQUERY UI Sorting the rows except the first cell

Tags: html, jquery-ui, row, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the JQuery UI Sortable() library and I am trying to sort the table rows except the first cell of each row.
Is this possible?

I am using the code below which drags the rows perfectly:

```
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
      var $originals = tr.children();
      var $helper = tr.clone();
      $helper.children().each(function(index) {
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
      });
      return $helper;
  };

  $("tbody").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
  }).disableSelection();
```

Is it possible to only move the rows except the first cell (or column) if that's makes sense?

Reason for this is that I have an input field carrying the ID value, however I don't want this to move or change with the rest of the row, I need it to stay in the correct order.

Requirement Diagram:
[image]

Your helped is much appreciated!

Thanks again,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made you a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4kv7uLe/2/) with your code-snippet that should fix your problem. 
There is a [offical example](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) too!

HTML (sample table)
Note the class "fixed" on the first TD:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<TABLE id="sortable">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <TR id="row1">
            <TD class="fixed">Data 1</TD>
            <TD>Data 2</TD>
            <TD>Data 3</TD>
            <TD>Data 4</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR id="row2">
            <TD class="fixed">Data 1</TD>
            <TD>Data 2</TD>
            <TD>Data 3</TD>
            <TD>Data 4</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR id="row3">
            <TD class="fixed">Data 1</TD>
            <TD>Data 2</TD>
            <TD>Data 3</TD>
            <TD>Data 4</TD>
        </TR>
    </tbody>
</TABLE>
```

Added `cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"` and `items: "td:not(.ui-state-disabled)"`.
After that you just add the class `"ui-state-disabled"` to any objects that you dont want to be sorted.
JQuery-UI-Part:

```
  var fixHelperModified = function (e, tr) {
      var $originals = tr.children();
      var $helper = tr.clone();
      $helper.children().each(function (index) {
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
      });
      return $helper;
  };

  $("table tr").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
      cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
      items: "td:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
  }).disableSelection();

  $(".fixed").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

Comment: Hi, WOW, thank you so much for your Example and support! That is nearly what im looking for, however instead of each <td> except the first to move, I need all the cells in the row except the first to move together. I take it this just requires adjusting the items or the class ?

Comment: @AlpaxJ1 JQuery-UI.Sortable has some issues with tables, so you will run into problems. If you can, try making a list or if you want to keep the table, try excluding your first row from the table.

Comment: Hi @AlpaxJ1 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: From your JFiddle, how would i go about only sorting the DATA 2 cells in a group together (like a row)?  IS this possible?

Comment: Updated my first try. I dont like how 2 tables are inside a table, but it seems that is the easiest way to solve your problem! Check it out and tell me if this is better!

Comment: PERFECT!, you hit it right on the nail, exactly what i was after. Thank you so much. Table inside a table i agree too is not ideal but it works for my needs! Thanks again.