# Drag, Drop and Display UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am a jQuery beginner, In a 3 column grid, I want to drag text from the first column to the second column and then display image, text and a youtube video in the third column.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I solved the problem using Checkboxes which show and hide dive accordingly for now. Will move to drag drop later.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is familliar to another question i allready answered here: 
-> [JQUERY UI Sorting the rows except the first cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369324/jquery-ui-sorting-the-rows-except-the-first-cell/26370537#26370537)

You just have to ignore the part where you dont want to sort the first column.